# Select data from database only for the current day using hql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in my project and I need to retrieve data from a MySQL database for only the current day.
how can I do this knowing that I have a colum 'date' using current_timestamp method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > CURDATE();`

Transformed to hibernate it could be:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from table where date > CURDATE()");
```

Or work with a parameter by get formatted timestamp in java:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
query.setParameter("date", timeStamp);
```